# How to change an element in 2D array by its index without changing others in Python? [Encountered error that will change other elements]

Tags: python

```
fullOfBombsCol = ["O"] * 6
fullOfBombs = [fullOfBombsCol] * 7
fullOfBombs[1][5] = 'x'
```

The result I get is :  
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x'], 
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x'],  
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x'],  
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x'],  
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x'],  
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x'],  
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'x']]  
which is not what I want to as I only want to change the last element of the second array in the array. 
Would appreciate if anyone can help! Thanks!

Comment: One way to make your array that avoids this shallow copy issue is to take `fullOfBombs = [["O" for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(7)]`

Comment: @BenGrossmann That makes it looks like one still doesn't understand it and is now just too afraid to use `['O'] * 6` :-P

Comment: @Kelly  I can see that, maybe `[[‘O’]*6 for _ in range(7)]` is better